# настройка bios для android studio

Tags: android-studio, bios

Подскажите, столкнулся с стандартной проблемой для AD Intel Haxm is required to run this AVD
VT-x is disableid in BIOS
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings(refer docunentation for yor computer)
Проблема в следующем,ноутбук sony vaio vgn-fw21zr Проблема в том что Биус максимально урезан, и я могу только поменять дату,время,и с чего загрузиться,соответственно вкладки VT-x там просто нет,можно как то решить эту проблему?)))

Comment: И расширенного режима редактирования биоса нет?

Answer (score 1):

Узнаю Sony :)

Для тех, кто в танке:

1. VT-x поддержка режима виртуализации в процессорах Intel
2. Эмулятор Android активно использует этот режим, для ускорения работы
3. Sony по каким-то своим соображениям блокирует поддержку VT-x в некоторых своих продуктах (не только Sony надо отметить).

Теперь [лонгрид как это сделать](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-enable-intel-vt-and-ahci-on-a-napa-santa-rosa-platform-phoenix-bios-vaio-laptop.189228/)